# UI Controls learning document and code example with Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android

The link below provides good learning resource.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/

However, there are many controls that I cannot find learning resource and code example.

For example some controls (e.g.ExpandableListView etc) on Visual Studio Toolbox are below.

**Is there a one stop learning resource and code example for these controls?**

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: https://youtu.be/Wj-WT4uWlKA. Here is some helpful

Comment: Yes, above article did not contains all of controls in toolbox, but you could learn these controls by api like this link(search whatever you want in search 
 bar).https://developer.xamarin.com/api/root/MonoAndroid-lib/

Comment: There is no code example for controls like ExpandableListView, and ActionMenuView etc. I wonder if there is a plan to provide code example for these controls from Xamarin?

Comment: I did not heard this kind of plan, but you can take a feature request in this link.https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues